# How create role to put in the database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq-to-sql, roles

i wish create a role for each user after that the user authenticate(login) to access to the application i will give some role to and save the role on the database.
I will make an example with the database "aspnet.mdf" and Linq toSql to store data but before i need  know how create role in c#(WPF) and  after created i wish add  roles on the database so doing i can assign for each user the right role that i wish .
DO you have some idea how do it right???
I will use the database "aspnet.mdf" as example because i see it good just to test my application (i need this feature to develop a project).

Thanks  a lot.

Nice Regards,

Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

If you're using ASP.NET's membership framework, you don't touch it using LinqToSql.  You use ASP.NET's [membership framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx).

Comment: Hi Will,
that's mean that i cannot use the aspnet.mdf as example to write down data with Linq ToSQl?..i need that database only to make a test because i see it right ...when i will develop my project i will create my database of course..I don't wish use ASP.NET as i have not knowledge about it.:)

Comment: Membership in ASP.NET is a complex framework that extends beyond the database itself.  If you try to modify all your aspnet_ tables directly, you may not do it correctly, causing the framework to fail.  Therefore, for membership, use the framework.  Use LinqToSql for everything else.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you might acomplish something like that.  I am not sure why you would want to create a role for every user though, kind of defeats the purpose of roles.  Anyways something like this will work:

```
// Check User exists
if (Membership.GetUser("admin") == null)
    Membership.CreateUser("admin", "pass", "admin@domain.com");            

// Check Role exists or create
if (!Roles.RoleExists("AdminRole"))
    Roles.CreateRole("AdminRole");

// Check Users in Roles
if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("admin", "AdminRole"))
    Roles.AddUserToRole("admin", "AdminRole");
```